# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1184).

Comment: @Caramdir: thanks.  I used to be "with it", but then they changed what "it" was. Now, what I'm "with" isn't "it", and what's "it" seems weird and scary.  It'll happen to you!

Comment: @Geoff: It is OK to add answers here which only suggest possible ads? Would this confuse the ad-extractor? We could open an own discussion "question" for this.

Comment: @Martin: Kjell wrote me he'll send a banner next week, for texample.net/TikZ gallery. Also, I asked C. Schenk (MiKTeX) (he answered he'll send a banner), Palle (LaTeX Font Catalogue), Graham (TeX Catalogue) and will ask further people .. I like the site owners to agree and perhaps to provide their own image for linking.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks a lot, I agree with you. I was planning to contact you and Joseph about contacting Kjell. One another site would be the UK TeX FAQ.

Comment: @Martin: Since the UK TeX FAQ site doesn't show a logo, just text, I drafted a logo and sent it for asking. Asked also regarding Kile, TeXnicCenter and will continue to contact projects. Perhaps they would send a banner or would allow to use their logo for linking.

Comment: @Stefan: You could add detexify to that list.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with {top-7}? Are only the top seven ads shown?

Comment: @Martin: See [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). Btw. perhaps let's clean a bit above, regarding now obsolete talks.

Comment: @Stefan: Should we also add TUG and TeXLive? There is also DANTE, and even a link to `comp.text.tex` (as Google Group) would be possible. Many new people might not known these and would benefit from getting pointed there.

Comment: @Martin: true! Let's do that. I'll take freely usable logos from Wikimedia Commons, refer to there, at the moment TUG and Dante.

Comment: @Martin: comp.text.tex added

Comment: MiKTeX and Detexify will come, Christian resp. Daniel are working on a banner.

Comment: @GoeffDalgas: Adding new ads is currently broken. See my bug report at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98975/community-ads-posts-are-taken-as-trivial-and-converted-to-comments.

Comment: @Martin fix deploying currently; give it 2 minutes?

Comment: Uh, I have to ask about the legalese: What's the license that applies to the ads? Are they Subscriber Content according to section 3 of the [sx ToS](http://stackexchange.com/legal)?

Answer (score 32):

[image: From answers to packages]

Comment: A tribute to our great TeXperts! `=)`

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: @Paulo: Nice one! Which SW did you used?

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! I used Gimp on a Windows 7 machine, the Calibri bold font, the TeX.SX logo and [this PNG plain box](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/38964/128/box_delivery_generic_inventory_package_product_icon). `=)`

Comment: According to that page, the box icon is under a “No Derivative Works” license :(

Comment: @Petr: Terribly sorry. I redesigned the box, I think it's safe now. `:-)`

Comment: I like the new box even better! It looks more like a "package" that you would get in the mail.

Comment: Looks fantastic.

Answer (score 28):

[image: CTAN -- The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network]

Comment: Taken from the old, original CTAN logo still available from http://dante.ctan.org/search.html.

Comment: Now updated with gradient background which is closer to the original logo.

Answer (score 23):

[image: TeX Live]

Comment: Adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Logo_TeX_Live.svg. I'm happy to share the SVG version if anyone wants to change it.

Comment: i like the idea, but the background on my screen is so dark that it's hard to read the text or see the lion.

Comment: I can change the color of the lower text, but the lion is more difficult. I tried to change it to white but it doesn't look good. It's based on the 'official' logo where the lion is not visible any better :-(

Comment: @barbara: How is it now? The lion is still very difficult to get right on this background.

Comment: sorry i failed to notice your question earlier.  the lion is still kind of wimpy, but the text is clear.  good work.

Answer (score 22):

[image: TeX.SX Meta]

Comment: I like the design.   I think it could probably do with a tagline to give at least an idea of what meta is for.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks for the idea. I updated the logo with the text Martin used on his image.

Comment: @Paulo: Great work also. However, please don't use my English as reference. ;-)

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. Don't worry, at least _your_ English is way better than _my_ English. `=P`

Comment: This ad is on the main page right now (nice!), but for me it looks a bit distorted. I guess the reason is that it doesn't follow the requirement **220 x 250 pixel**. Could you bring the image to that format, @Paulo?

Comment: @Hendrik: I'm so sorry, I didn't noticed that! Something wrong happened when I exported to a transparent PNG, the image size was recalculated to the layer size. Now it's fixed. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 20):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: I'm confused, what does twitter have to do with tex.SX and why do we care if people use twitter?

Comment: @th. see http://twitter.com/#!/stacktex

Answer (score 20):

[image: UK TeX FAQ - Frequently Asked Questions and Answers]

Comment: I got the ok from Robin (UK). Since the site contains text without graphics, I drafted the banner.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Lowering the entry barrier to the TeX world]

Comment: Impressive artwork!

Comment: @Paulo: It's not mine - this is the TeXworks icon, created by various users when the project was looking for a visual identity. It's inspired by the Mac convention that editor programs include a pen in their icon (see for example TextEdit).

Comment: Some text would help, I think.  Something like "TeXWorks: a cross-platform editor"?

Comment: @Alan: In the first instance, I've just added 'TeXworks' (in Computer Modern, of course). I'm a bit concerned about the size if I put too much text in

Comment: Could you fit "editor" in small caps right-aligned under "works" and aligned vertically with the E of TeX?

Comment: @Alan: I've gone for centred text in version 3 - does this work?

Comment: @Joseph I've put up the version of what I had in mind.  I don't know if the way I've created it is correct, though.

Comment: @Alan: The way I did my ones was to take the 256 x 256 .png from the TeXworks site, resize it in The Gimp. I then made a `standalone` PDF file containing the TeX part, and overlaid the two in The Gimp before adding a white background layer.

Comment: I used Illustrator, but basically the same process. If you like this one, we can leave it up.

Comment: @Alan: Perhaps take a look at http://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2011q3/004537.html - there are some suggestions for adjustment from the developers.

Answer (score 18):

[image: MacTeX - TeX on Mac OS X]

Comment: The MacTeX Lion drawing by [Duane Bibby](http://www.tug.org/tug2003/bulletin/bibby/), created to celebrate the success of TeX on Mac OS X, was [presented to the Grand Wizard, Don Knuth](http://www.tug.org/tug2003/mactex/mings/) in January 2004. It's been taken for the MacTeX Logo. In agreement with Richard Koch it's used for the ad to MacTeX here. I took Latin Modern and Times Roman to write the name to come close to the usage.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Texmaker - Free cross-platform LaTeX editor]

Comment: Image created by Pascal Brachet, the developer of Texmaker, sent to me for the ad.

Answer (score 16):

[image: DANTE e.v.]

Comment: Logo from http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Logo_DANTE_e._V.svg?uselang=en by DANTE e.V. created with `dantelogo.sty`.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Comic Sans LaTeX ad]

Comment: Getting Comic Sans running with LaTeX isn't straightforward, XeLaTeX might be a better choice ;)

Comment: @doncherry: who said I used PDFTeX? In fact, I used LuaTeX. But I can assure you I used LaTeX (not TeX or ConTeXt) and it was straightforward :-)

Comment: I read about your use of LuaTeX, I was referring to the advice given in the "ad". Can you give me a hint how you set up LaTeX for use with CS?

Comment: Well, I use `fontspec`. The fact that it's LaTeX doesn't mean I'm using PDFTeX as the rendering engine, it just means the language used is LaTeX, which can be built with PDFTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX... and in that specific case I used LuaTeX to make use of a system font.

Comment: Credit goes to @Raphink for this great idea! I only put the text into a post-it note. `=)`

Answer (score 15):

[image: Visit Meta.TeX.SX]

Comment: Something quick & dirty. I actually did this with FireBug and removed some text from the HTML code of the meta site and added and placed the text by modifying the first listed question. The tags where there by chance, but I then decided to keep them because they actually fit there very well.

Comment: Here is a shot how it would look like [on the main site](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wnI6C.png) (done using some HTML trickery).

Answer (score 15):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Comment: Source: http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Logo_TUG.svg resp. ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2008/packaging/coverlabel.tgz by TeX Users Group. See also the [TUG logo competition](http://www.tug.org/logo/competition/).

Comment: And we're officially sponsoring the TUG now, so let's upvote this :-)

Answer (score 15):

[image: TeX.sx Community Polls]

Comment: Created by [Paulo Cereda](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) but posted by me due to a technical issue. Thank you very much for the image Paulo!

Comment: Thanks a million for fixing this issue, Martin! I'm glad to help! `=)`

Comment: @Paulo: No problem. It should now work again as usually.

Comment: Please, non 3D pie charts!!!

Comment: @PauloCereda: Can you please redo this image without 3D pie charts.

Comment: @Aditya: Sure, I'll work on a new version. `:)`

Comment: @Aditya: New image, also updated in the new thread. `:)`

Answer (score 14):

[image: CTAN HG: Mercurial Archive of CTAN]

Comment: Great idea, Martin!

Answer (score 14):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Comment: What is this (other than super cool)?

Comment: What is ConTeXt or the image? The image is Duane Bibby's drawing which was the logo of ConTeXt Meeting 2012 (http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2011/) which was held in a very nice castle. The image emphasizes a mixture of TeX, MetaPost, LuaTeX, XML, MathML - the building blocks of ConTeXt.

ConTeXt is a "super cool" alternative to LaTeX, capable of doing a lot more complex tricks, and with a magnificent community ...

Answer (score 12):

[image: TeX on Usenet]

Comment: Diagram of Usenet servers and clients by Benjamin D. Esham http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Usenet_servers_and_clients.svg (public domain)

Comment: If somebody has a better link, go forward and change it.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Stack Exchange TeX Blog]

Comment: The blog is now also linked on the top.

Comment: @Caramdir: When I posted this image, the blog link wasn't there yet, I swear! `=P` Anyway, should I remove it? We could save the ad space.

Comment: It appears that the link only shows up when there is a new post.

Answer (score 12):

[image: How you get TeX things done]

Answer (score 11):

[image: TeXShop - TeX editor and previewer for Mac OS X]

Comment: Posted and used TeXShop logo in agreement with Richard Koch, the developer of TeXShop.

Answer (score 10):

[image: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 9):

[image: LaTeXiT - Drag and drop LaTeX into anything!]

Comment: Great artwork! `:)`

Comment: Nothing to do with me. This is just the icon for the application!