# The prominent link to tex.blogoverflow.com has been buried

Tags: discussion, design, blog

I'm fairly sure that http://tex.blogoverflow.com/ used to be linked to in the top bar by the word "blog", close to the chat link.  Now we have a supply of good content on the blog it seems to have have moved into the crowd of links at the page footer.

I'm not about to file this as a bug report, since it has been the behaviour of the SOFU blogs before Blog Overflow and so I'm pretty sure is the desired behaviour.  Instead, I'd like to get some reaction here before raising it on SO meta.

In my opinion, the blog is valuable for promoting the site, and we should try to ensure that most users of the site are aware of it and can find it easily.  It has more business on the top bar than the "review" button, which could live next to or, with some more UI work, replace the "Unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The blog link appears in the main site footer at all times.

It only appears in the main site header when there is a new blog entry, for a duration of 24 hours.

You can also put a blog ad in the [Community Promotion Ads](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), if you like.

Comment: So we can fix this ourselves by having a new blog post every day...