# Why isn't our blog linked from the main page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The prominent link to tex.blogoverflow.com has been buried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/the-prominent-link-to-tex-blogoverflow-com-has-been-buried)

I just got in the situation that I wanted to find a blog entry I know to be on the tex.se blog. However, how to find the blog itself?

[image]

Apparently, the *blog* link appears on the main page only together with the red *new* indicator when there is some new post. While I certainly like the *new* indicator, I found it pretty strange that the blog basically disappears whenever there is no new content.

Even if you know that it is there, it is surprisingly hard to find it! If one tries to search for it on main, you won't get any useful hint. I finally found it by searching for "blog" on meta until I found a post that (thankfully) contained a link.

So am I missing something or is there a good reason to *not* have a permanent *blog* link from main (and meta)?

> **Proposal:** Make the *blog* link **appear permanently** on in the link bar on the top with the red *new* indicator showing up if there
>   is some new post.

Comment: Duplicate of [The prominent link to tex.blogoverflow.com has been buried](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1694/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn: Well, partly. The answer to the linked question (which I did not find before, thanks!) describes *how* it works, but neither *why* nor if it can be *fixed*. I had never considered looking at the very bottom for the link and I assume that I am not the only one.

Comment: Given that the linked answer was posted by Jeff, I doubt that there will be much movement on this. Since it's the same across all the sites, you might want to raise the issue on meta.stackoverlow.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I see. (Didn't know before who Jeff is).