# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2046).

Comment: Does this imply that the old community ads somehow expire? Or is this extra thread just for clarity?

Comment: @Martin This is partly to get extra eyes on these, and also to allow for some measure of cycling (like if people tired of seeing a particular ad). Unlike with Stack Overflow's open source ads, we don't restrict reposting ads from before. But, unless you want to just have the same adset all the time, this is a way to see a new set of ads if there is desire for it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Do the old ads now expire or not?

Comment: @Martin Yes, the old post expires, but you're free to repost the ads from it if you want to recycle any. Sorry that I was confusing

Comment: @Martin On that subject, though, you should still redesign the face of any ad whose destination you're recycling. Y'know, keep things fresh (this is exempting scenarios where the ad barely had any run such as being posted only in the last month).

Comment: @GraceNote: Slightly naive question; I reposted an advert from the previous round with *exactly* the same markdown. i.e. it's using the previously uploaded image. The previous question is now closed, but I imagine it will remain. Will my approach cause any problems?

Comment: @Mark We can overlook it, but consider if the ad could just be redesigned. Give it a brand new look so that people don't have to stare at the exact same image when it turns up, aye?

Comment: @GraceNote: I only added it three days ago. ;)

Comment: @Mark Haha, in that case as mentioned, if it was something just posted in the last month or two, you probably don't need to cycle the image because it probably got little air time in that period.

Comment: @GraceNote: Thanks. I was a little concerned about using a link to the same image in two places as it's uncommon on SE.

Comment: Why is an animated GIF not allowed?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Because the are really annoying would be my guess.

Answer (score 29):

[image: CTAN -- The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1501/5763

Comment: The font is soooo ugly

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: Feel free to make a better version. `:)`

Answer (score 29):

[image: Answer the Unanswered]

Comment: Based on [this thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1560).

Comment: The linked thread mentions a Wednesday and a Sunday, but not a Saturday...?

Comment: @Werner: I think we need to update that thread. `:)` For the last sessions, Saturday became the chosen day, so I'm lost too. I'll check. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda We seem to have standardised on the 2100 slot, I guess because this suits most of the 'regulars'. Nice ad, by the way!

Answer (score 28):

[image: From answers to packages]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1504/5763

Answer (score 27):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Comment: We are [institutional member](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-is-institutional-member-of-the-tex-users-group/) of the TeX's User Group.

Answer (score 26):

[image: UK TeX FAQ - Frequently Asked Questions and Answers]

Comment: The FAQ is useful - I would link it at least until we've got our own FAQ or the [FAQ tab on the question page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/does-the-faq-tab-work-correctly) is working properly.

Comment: As the FAQ is 'curated', I think it makes a great complement to TeX.sx. Robin Fairbairns does an amazing job.

Answer (score 24):

[image: LaTeXiT - Drag and drop LaTeX into anything!]

Comment: Seeing as I only posted this a couple of days ago, I think that it's new enough. ;)

Comment: Wow! I made this icon on a whim 5 years ago and offered it to the developer of LaTeXiT... what a nice surprise to see it pop up on the side of TeX.SE :)

Comment: It's a smashing icon. I think it may be the best one here!

Answer (score 23):

[image: TeX.SX Meta]

Comment: For our own good.

Answer (score 23):

[image: TeX Live]

Comment: General TeX Live ad without version number

Comment: The source file(s) can be accessed at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tex-logo. Feel free to modify it. Please see the copyright information at http://www.ctan.org/lion.html

Comment: If this ad makes the threshold, [the other TeX Live ad](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2060/4012) should probably be pulled, right?

Comment: @doncherry: I deleted the other TeX Live ad now (which was originally also by me but reposted from the first ad page by Martin Schröder).

Answer (score 22):

[image: DANTE e.v.]

Comment: At least 9 TeX.SX users, who are active on meta.TeX.SX, [are member](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1566/213) of the DANTE TeX users group.

Comment: Is it just me or is the space between _German_ and _TeX_ a bit too small (or not even there?) compared to the other two spaces in that line?

Comment: the sub title is wrong! It is "The german speaking TeX Users Group"

Comment: Can you make the source available somewhere?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Sure, I think I have the file at home, where I'm at the weekend. But it's easy to rebuild, I think, so making it even better besides inserting "speaking".

Answer (score 22):

[image: Lowering the entry barrier to the TeX world]

Comment: Still 'Lowering the Barrier' :-)

Answer (score 22):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Comment: Recently added, and ConTeXt deserves promotion.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Comic Sans LaTeX ad]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5763

Comment: Is there any special licence for this ad? I mean, can I repost it at other places (e.g. my blog)?

Comment: @tohecz: No, yes. See [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal), section 3.

Comment: @Canageek: For a non-answer, see our little discussion at [an earlier version of this ad](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1720/4012). Also, there's [`comicsans`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comicsans), but I never got it running. I might actually post a question about that some time ... :)

Comment: @Canageek: Stop this chatter - it has nothing to do with the ad. If you are _really_ interested in using that font with TeX, you know where to ask (not here).

Comment: @Canageek & Martin: Ooops ... http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79790/4012 `;)`

Answer (score 21):

[image: CTAN HG: Mercurial Archive of CTAN]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1891/5763

Answer (score 20):

[image: Texmaker - Free cross-platform LaTeX editor]

Comment: The developer Pascal Brachet announced a new version of this editor for the end of December 2011.

Comment: It'd be great if something could be done about the terrible kerning of "LaTeX" in this ad. Probably just put it in the TeX-y shifted capitals?

Answer (score 19):

[image: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Comment: Added just some weeks ago to the first ad topic. This is the journal of the TeX Users Group of which TeX.SX is a member. TeX.SX has been reviewed in TUGboat 32:1 (by Jim Hefferon) and will be covered more extensively in TUGboat 32:3 (by me).

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that it'll be a while until these reviews are freely available?

Comment: @doncherry Both are freely available. The first: [Which way to the forum](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100heff.pdf), the second is accessible in preproduction status, don't know if linking it is acceptable, it's not printed yet.

Answer (score 18):

[image: TeX on Usenet]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1543/5763

Answer (score 18):

[image: Stack Exchange TeX Blog]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1668/5763

Answer (score 18):

[image: How you get TeX things done]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1971/5763

Comment: Wow! I thought that was dead, but it seems it just posted a new issue!

Answer (score 17):

[image: MacTeX - TeX on Mac OS X]

Comment: This MacTeX Lion drawing done by [Duane Bibby](http://www.tug.org/tug2003/bulletin/bibby/) has been taken for the MacTeX Logo. In agreement with Richard Koch it's used for the ad to MacTeX here. I took Latin Modern and Times Roman to write the name to come close to the usage in the original logo.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1185/5763

Answer (score 16):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Hi! Academia.SE has a nicely growing community discussing all sorts of matters relating to academic life, from grad student to emeritus professor… We think it could be of interest to a good part of the TeX SE community!

Answer (score 14):

[image: arara is a TeX automation tool]

Comment: This is just a (very!) rough scratch I copied from the documentation; I'm pretty sure Paulo can make a much finer ad.

Answer (score 13):

[image: TeXShop - TeX editor and previewer for Mac OS X]

Comment: Perhaps this ad should mention that TeXShop is an editor for Mac? Texmaker and TeXworks each have it in their ad. I just imagine that somebody might think this is a shop for LaTeX (not latex ...) merchandise.

Answer (score 10):

[image: TeX.sx Community Polls]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1570/5763

Answer (score 10):

[image: Help this community grow!]

Comment: Full disclosure: I am active on that site. I think there is a reasonable overlap between the audience of this site and the Mathematica site, and of course there are some cross-over questions related to the LaTeX capabilities of Mathematica.