# Follow and help the Typography.SE proposal!

Tags: discussion, community, stackexchange

There is a proposal for a [Typography.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography) site. I leave up to each of you to have their opinion on the proposal, but I think it needs more attention!

So please go to its [Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography), make your opinion on the example question, upvote those you like or downvote those you don't like, and add your own if you wish! (Remember, you can vote only 5 times). If you want to get news for this site in your SE inbox, you can follow it (there's a link for it on top left).

So again the link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography

Comment: i agree it's a useful proposal, have forwarded their invitation to the list typo-l@listserv.heanet.ie and have had a positive response already.

Comment: The folks at [Graphicdesign.sx](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) pointed out that Typography is [on-topic there](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/422/scope-expansion-project-update-oct-22). Why do we need another project?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I know that there's this discussion whether it's on topic or not. On the other hand, I know that my proposed questions (on Area51) are off-topic on GD and on-topic on Typography.

Comment: @tohecz: I doubt that. See [here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/422/scope-expansion-project-update-oct-22).

Comment: I agree with Martin. Why do we need a separate site for this?

Comment: looks like it failed.  at least it was closed, to avoid siphoning off support from graphic design.  too bad -- i'm really disappointed.  graphic design has too much material that's off-topic for me, so i won't be joining.

Comment: @barbarabeeton [Apparantly](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1408/16595) not the first time that a typography-related StackExchange site has not survived the Area-51 status …

Comment: I've closed on the grounds that the Powers That Be did not go for the idea

Comment: @JosephWright no prob, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Typography.SE site proposal was closed as a duplicate of [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I've created a [community ad](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/community-promotion-ads-2012/) for it, [which you can vote on](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2844/7880).

[image: Terrible Typography.SE ad]

If someone wants to create a better one, well, I know I suck. Please feel free to create something awesome with a duck or whatever.

Comment: How about [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QwmDk.png)?

Comment: @Silex Make it into a proposal and let the community vote on it.

Comment: @SIlex: Is it just me, or is the kerning in "Typography.SE" wrong? If so, is it deliberate?