# Follow and help the English Language Learners SE proposal!

Tags: discussion, community, stackexchange

There is a proposal for an [English Language Learners SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) site. I leave up to each of you to have their opinion on the proposal, but I think it needs more attention! Also TeX.SE could benefit if some people (I do include myself) asking questions or giving answers could enhance their knowledge of the English language.

So please go to ELL's [Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), make your opinion on the example questions, upvote those you like or downvote those you don't like, and add your own if you wish! (Remember, you can vote only 5 times). If you want to get news for this site in your SE inbox, you can follow it (there's a link for it on top left).

So again the link:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners

(When you are at Area 51, you might also like to regard [Follow and help the Typography.SE proposal!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/follow-and-help-the-typography-se-proposal))

Comment: ELL has been successfully launched at: https://ell.stackexchange.com/