# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's that time again! We are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2956).

Comment: I suggest that we try to think out new community ads. [The statistics](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2046) show that the impact of the old ones is quite small. I would add the majority of the old ones only if we're not able to think about better new ones. And even in that case, I would consider it better to refresh the design of the ads.

Comment: it's stated that the `[community-ads]` tag must always be used, but there's no place in the answer window on this question to do so.  so, how then?

Comment: @tohecz -- while i agree that some redesign would freshen the ads, when an entity (e.g. tug or tugboat) has a recognized logo, how do you change that without also diminishing the value of the logo?

Comment: @barbarabeeton you don't need to care about the tag, the question is properly tagged. Ad redesign: I agree it's complicated, still the low impact shows that there's not a large interest in these ones. We can maybe make a metapost about TeX-related institutions and create one fresh and colorful ad pointing to this thread?

Comment: @tohecz At least in part I suspect the 'click throughs' are from a subset of users, and so once they've seen the ad once they don't look again. That suggests we need new things to advertise!

Comment: @tohecz (and others) I've opened http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/what-makes-a-good-community-advert to deal with the meta-meta question of what to advertise :-)

Comment: Well, is it the time of the year again for the next round?

Comment: @quazgar It *is* that time of the year.

Answer (score 44):

[image: TeX Live]

Answer (score 40):

[image: TeXample.net – example resources for TeX users]

Comment: Thanks for adding this! I felt kinda bad about the earlier proposal going away, but it just wouldn’t have worked in the wrong format, I’m afraid.

Comment: @doncherry I suppose that the system ignores the ad as long as it has a wrong format...

Answer (score 38):

[image: CTAN -- The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network]

Comment: [2012 community Promotion Ads](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2046/15717) can be retained with some additions

Answer (score 31):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Comment: We are institutional member of this group, and it's the biggest and international TeX users group, so it's good to link to it. It's the original logo, still, so no reason to change.

Comment: Please, do you have it in large resolution/vector? I tried to find it on TUG pages, but not succesfully. I guess it would use "WANTS YOU!" sign below the logo. I have some idea for the TUGboat one as well.

Answer (score 29):

[image: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Comment: The journal of our partner TeX organization, where we are institutional member. Several fellow TeX.SE members published articles in this journal, and the journal already dealt with TeX.SE topics.

Answer (score 29):

[image: writeLaTeX.com]

Comment: One of the suggestions in the meta discussion [Link to online LaTeX compiler](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler?cb=1) suggested the community ads would be a good place to have a link - so I've created the above for [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com)

Answer (score 28):

[image: TeX.SX Meta]

Answer (score 27):

[image: DANTE e.v.]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2051/5763

Comment: Any plans to incorporate the improvement suggestions over at the 2012 post? I'm mostly referring to Herbert's suggestion, which would result in something like "German-speaking TeX Users Group" or "German-language ...". (I think that's @StefanKottwitz, who created this ad.)

Comment: @doncherry: At least the typography of the last line should be corrected. I don't have the source, though.

Comment: I spent more than one hour looking for the dante logo font, found some information on the MetaType1 5 letter source but no pfb, tfm, ore otf file, just some dead links. I know Herbert has it, but it doesn't seem to be easily available for the public. If somebody has it, it's probably straightforward to rebuild the simple logo even with the sane fonts as in the dtk.

Answer (score 25):

[image: Stack Exchange TeX Blog]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2059/5763

Answer (score 25):

[image: The bidi package]

Comment: how about mirroring "bidi Package" coming from the right, or just "bidi" if there isn't enough room?  (quite a delightful creature to look at; maybe less so in person.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: See the documentation of `bidi` package for what symbolises `bidi` package. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the pointer; very illuminating intro!  (my memory said "assyrian", which is a bit off.  i love visiting museum exhibits with antiquities from that region.  i hope you've seen the quote on the [title page of tugboat 33:1](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/titlepage.pdf).)

Comment: Just another upvoting!

Comment: I'm using this package in the Persian language every day. It has very useful features.   Thanks to Vafa Khalighi.

Comment: I'm really unhappy about the bad typography of this ad.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to avoid such a horrible font?

Comment: The link goes 404. :-(

Answer (score 22):

[image: UK TeX FAQ - Frequently Asked Questions and Answers]

Comment: I think the FAQ is still valid. I made this simple picture and don't plan to design a new one, so I post this. Feel free to redesign if anybody would like to.

Comment: Could we get a TeX logo in the second line, please?

Comment: @MartinSchröder The Web site uses it this way in its heading ;-) Sure, I will look for the source file.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Some of us _really_ don't like the use of logos in sentences or other running text :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: It really contrasts with the _logo_ above it.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes, I'd seen that :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: The “Te” kern and the wide “eX” gap makes the word TeX look weird especially in serif fonts, that is why I personally prefer the logo even in running text.

Answer (score 21):

[image: TeX on Usenet]

Comment: I guess many young TeX users don't know about TeX on the Usenet. So I think a pointer to it would be good. It has a great history, and it's still active.

Comment: agreed.  i was going to add it, but ran into problems with the "i am a human" response.  new glasses won't help; guess i'll have to check the resolution on my screen.  (or maybe it's trying to tell me something?)

Comment: This ad should really be overhauled imho. It doesn't tell the user (who's unfamiliar with comp.text.tex) anything really about what's behind it. It's about "computers/computation/computing/competence/?", "Text", and "TeX", well that's not surprising. And the illustration is mostly cryptic, a closer look may show it's a "computer network" of some sort, but that could be any number of things.

Comment: The illustration points to a unique characteristic of `comp.text.tex`: it's a distributed TeX discussion system. In contrast, TeX.SE, web forums and even mailing lists are centralized: in case of a server maintenance or failure the system could be down - comp.text.tex would remain available. The monospaced font was choosen to remind of the older times - I accessed the Usenet firstly on monochrome text terminals. Well, it could be explained in the image. What would you add? I already like seeing a "TeX network" as a teaser.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Joseph brought up [the question in general](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/what-makes-a-good-community-advert) (perhaps after seeing these comments), so I wrote an answer there, which doesn't mention this ad specifically, but can probably be applied to it.

Answer (score 21):

[image: LaTeX Community]

Comment: I'm the current maintainer of this site which exists since January 2007. It's different to TeX.SE, as it offers news, articles, and a forum with open discussion where especially LaTeX beginners get help.

Comment: although all the other text is flush left, i think flushing the url to the right might give an interesting balance.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don’t really see why the URL needs to be there at any rate ... if people are interested, they’ll click the ad, they won’t manually type in the URL.

Comment: @doncherry The URL is for people who don't click but who may remember having seen it.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Since it’s identical to the name, I wouldn’t think the URL is necessary here, but it doesn’t really matter in the end.

Answer (score 21):

[image: DeTeXify - LaTeX symbol classifier]

Comment: Just would like know: Are you a fan of site like us ? or the author of site ? Thanks for the promo

Comment: Definitely a fan, for me this has been the single most useful (time saving) site.

Answer (score 20):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Comment: From http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2053/5763

Comment: I met this ad much before I knew ConTeXt and to be honest, I didn't click it because I had no idea what it is about. It definitely needs some explanation.

Answer (score 19):

[image: The Persian-speaking TeX Users Group]

Comment: I Love ParsiLaTeX!

Comment: I am one of the current admins of this site. [Our forum](http://forum.parsilatex.com/) has over **2000** registered users and over **17000** Q&As about TeX, LaTeX and friends.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Lets you search through milions of LaTeX code snippets to find the equation you need.]

Comment: If you didn't like it and wanted to improve it, I have the gimp `.scf` source of it. And thanks [Kannappan Sampath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8601094#8601094) for discovering the site!

Answer (score 15):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 15):

[image: 21st century LaTeX Editor ShareLaTeX]

Comment: very fetching lion.  but what's the apostrophe in "21'st"?

Comment: hmmm good point!

Answer (score 12):

[image: LaTeXiT - Drag and drop LaTeX into anything!]

Comment: Recycled (it's still relevant) from http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2047/9043